# Beyond Watson's lemma

Tags: cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, laplace-transform

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a smooth function, which I wish to approximate near $0$. Watson's Lemma implies that I can find a smooth function $a:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^1 e^{-s/x} a(s)\: ds+O(x^N), \quad \forall N$$
In fact, I only need to choose the Taylor series of $a$ at 0 appropriately to achieve this; so many such $a$ provide such an approximation.

How much better of an approximation is possible? For example, can I choose $a$ so that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^1 e^{-s/x} a(s)\: ds+O(e^{-\epsilon/x})$$
for some $\epsilon>0$?

Edit: As Christian Remling points out, one needs to admit more general $a$. For example, one could take $f$ given by the above formula, with $a\in L^1$ which vanishes to infinite order at $0$. Then $f$ would be smooth, but one could not obtain the above desired exponential approximation.

So this question is answered! But following Chrisitian, perhaps the better question is: is there a class of generalized functions $a$ which makes the above approximation always possible?

Comment: Offhand, I'd suspect that you cannot do better, since Watson's lemma for general smooth functions is (to my perception) about finite Taylor expansions... which generically have polynomial error terms. But I'd need to think through the proof... After all, why mightn't there be a different family than polynomials to approximate functions locally...?

Comment: The question only becomes interesting if you admit more general $a$. Otherwise you can just start out with a non-smooth $a$, *define* $f(x)=(1/x)\int_0^1 e^{-s/x}a(s)\, ds$, and then there cannot be a smooth $b(s)$ because even in $L^1$, the Laplace transform is uniquely determined by this kind of asymptotics on $(0,\epsilon)$, so  you'd have to have $b=a$ on $(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: In fact, it's not so easy perhaps to find a class of $a$ that's not vulnerable to this simple attack. For example, if you try $a\in L^1$, I can probably beat this with a measure.